# Apache Tomcat 8.5 . Error: Service terminated with service specific error incorrect function

Tags: apache, service, tomcat8

i have installed apache tomcat 8.5 one month ago with java 1.8 on Windows Server 2008 and it works ok.
now the service is stopped and i'm not able to restart it from apache configuration or Windows Services . It is always stopped.
i got the following error: "service terminated with service specific error incorrect function".

[image: error description]

ther error in Windows Event viewer does not saying nothing more:

[image: event viewer]

even its details tab:

[image: event details]

What can i do?

Comment: SOLVED  i open "configure Tomcat" nad in java tab i flag "use default" and i it works again

Answer (score 20):

I was trying to install Apache Tomcat/8.5.31 as Windows service and i was also facing the same error.

For me what finally worked was following these steps. Go to Tomcat installation directory's `bin` folder. You will see two EXEs (`tomcat8.exe` and `tomcat8w.exe`). `tomcat8w.exe` is a GUI application for monitoring and configuring Tomcat services. Double-click it and then go to `Java` tab
1) Enable the check box for `Use default`
2) In `Java Classpath:` section, specify the path to `bootstrap.jar` and `tomcat-juli.jar`. These should be present in your tomcat installation's `bin` directory itself:

```
<path_to_tomcat_installation>\bin\bootstrap.jar;<path_to_tomcat_installation>\bin\tomcat-juli.jar
```

[image]

To get more help, you may check the log at the following location provided you installed your Tomcat as Windows service using default `LogPath` option as described in the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Installing_services): `%SystemRoot%\System32\LogFiles\Apache`

**UPDATE**: In another recent installation, i noticed that despite having configuration settings exactly similar to another working setup, i was still getting `Incorrect function` error under `System` log in `Event Viewer`. This time, i had to uncheck the `Use default` option and had to explicitly provide path to `jvm.dll` as shown below:

[image]

`Java Classpath` setting was still required as explained above.

Comment: Same problem installing as not-admin user: fixed editing "Java virtual machine".. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32457425/cant-install-tomcat-7-as-a-service-in-windows

Answer (score 3):

Currently I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter running Tomcat 9 & had the same problem. This happened after I ran Windows updates & restarted the Server.

Error messages below. (The blanked out text is my private data.)

[Error showed when attempting to start the service.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DN5mz.png)

[Error in System Event Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/few8E.png)

The following steps fixed the issue...

1. Navigate to your tomcat9w.exe Location: \Tomcat9\bin\
2. [Right click your tomcat9w.exe and select Run as administrator.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYG8I.png)
3. [Select the Java tab. Select Use default, Apply, & OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcqD6.png)
4. Start your service.

Note: I unchecked the "Use default" box after I was able to get the service running correctly. Because I wanted to retain my existing configuration. Going forward the service has continued to work correctly.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing some issue with Tomcat 9 and Java 13 (tried all previously mentioned solutions but nothing worked). When I downgraded it to Java 11 and Pointed the jvm.dll from JDK 11 my issue got fixed (or Use Default if JAVA_HOME is set to Java 11).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case the only way I could get it to work, was to go to the "Startup" tab and change "Mode" from "JVM" to "Java". After that, it started fine and was able to confirm that by visiting the localhost.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(Definitely not an expert)

I fixed this issue by (re)installing Java. I was using the Java SDK downloaded by IntelliJ. Although I was able to direct Tomcat to that download during installation, it returned this "error service terminated" message at runtime. Instead I installed Java SDK directly from Oracle, Tomcat found the installation immediately during installation (I didn't need to point it), and this error disappeared.

It's possible the Java installation by IntelliJ was incomplete somehow and is the underlying cause of the problem, but I am definitely not an expert.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by reinstalling Tomcat:

1. Search the *Command Prompt* icon
2. Right-click on it
3. Select *Run as administrator*
4. Change the folder to the `bin` folder of Tomcat
5. Execute `appserver uninstall`
6. Execute `appserver install`

It solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I followed the below steps to fix the the above issue. it may help if someone still face the same.

---

Step 1.  opened the installation directory : tomcat9w.exe Location: \Tomcat9\bin\

Step 2. Browsed the Jvm.dll path  under "Java Tab" in Tomcat where it has installed

Step 3. Run the service but still faced same.

Step 4. then, Opened  ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin>startup.bat  --> entered.

Finally it got fixed .

Comment: Write arrow marked