# Cannot install Tomcat8.5 as a service

Tags: windows, tomcat, service

I tried to update a Tomcat 8.5 installation to the latest point-release.

It was working before the upgrade, but not after, so I rolled-back to the previous version, but I cannot get the service to install correctly for the old version either:

"The BOEXI40Tomcat service terminated with the following service-specific error:
Incorrect function."

If I run Tomcat directly from the command line  (startup.bat) then it runs fine, so it must be something weird about the service itself, but I just can't see what's wrong. Any ideas?

Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.32
Server built:          Jun 20 2018 19:50:35 UTC
Server number:         8.5.32.0
OS Name:               Windows Server 2016
OS Version:            10.0
Architecture:          amd64
Java Home:             D:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessOb
JVM Version:           8.1.045
JVM Vendor:            SAP AG

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache Tomcat 8.5 . Error: Service terminated with service specific error incorrect function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45842730/apache-tomcat-8-5-error-service-terminated-with-service-specific-error-incorr)

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz  No, I'd already seen that.

Comment: Nevertheless I believe your question is a duplicate (same symptoms) of the one I cited. If you post your solution to that question, I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it turns out that the problem for me was a set of three commands targetting version 9

Not sure how they got in there, but found only when looking at Tomcat9w.exe - in the lower panel - removing them appears to have been the solution.

```
--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
```